# Binding OneWayToSource with OneTime initalization of target

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a `DataGrid` with editable cells bound to their respective values in the view model of the respective items.

Initially, the data is loaded and displayed to the user, who can then edit the data in the grid.

Binding is working as it should (in my case with `UpdateSourceTrigger=OnPropertyChanged`), but due to conversions between `double` (view model) and `string` (UI), a `TwoWay` binding would cause annoying UI bugs like making decimal separators or zeros after a decimal point disappear when typed by the user.

**Two faulty solutions are:**

- Making the property a `string` in the view model, and doing the necessary conversions inside the view model.

  - **Problem:** brings me a strange problem of incompatible cultures between the UI and the view model (and I don't expect the view model to know the UI's culture)
- Using a `OneWayToSource` binding. This eliminates all UI bugs as the VM stops sending back parsed and reconverted values.

  - **Problem:** I can't (or don't know how to) initialize the values in the grid with the loaded data.

So, can I somehow use a `OneWayToSource` binding "after" a `OneTime` binding, or somehow sum the two?

I tried to bind `FallbackValue` and `TargetNullValue` to the source values, but they don't accept bindings.

Comment: Setting UpdateSourceTrigger = LostFocus or Explicit partially solves the problem.

Comment: "*TwoWay binding would cause annoying UI bugs like making decimal separators disappear when typed by the user*" - what exactly do you mean by this? It should be fixed, because TwoWay Binding is the way to go.

Comment: I dealt with this problem and found out that this happening due  is not to PropertyChanged.
Even if the event does not occur (since the value does not change) Binding still discards the last dot and zeros after dot.
Most likely this is due to the internal implementation of the PropertyDescriptor - the bindings work through it.
If you speak Russian, I recently gave an explanation of their work here https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2650880.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a hacky workaround that involves using two properties, the original and a string dedicated to the user for smooth behavior. Use a specific converter for that purpose. (I think I'll adopt this as a pattern for future cases)

This works for cases where the view model does not change the property, only the user changes the property. (If you want a truly two way interaction where the view model also changes the property, you need to set the string property to null whenever you need to change the property)

**In the view model:**

The differences from a standard code are:

- adding a string property without logic
- adding a notification for this property when the original property changes

Code:

```
private double? _TheProperty;

public double? TheProperty { get { return _TheProperty ; } set { SetTheProperty (value); } }
public string ThePropertyUserString { get; set; } //for UI only!!! Don't change via code

private void SetTheProperty(double? value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        //implement validation errors if necessary
        //using IDataErrorInfo and ValidatesOnDataErrors
        //this type of validation is the only I found that helps enabling/disabling command buttons
    }

    //do your logic
    _TheProperty = value;

    //notify
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged("TheProperty", ...);
        PropertyChanged("ThePropertyUserString", ...);
    }
}
```

**In the XAML:**

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                      Mode="TwoWay"
                      Converter="{StaticResource DoubleUserStringConverter}">
            <Binding Path="TheProperty" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"/>
            <Binding Path="ThePropertyUserString"/>
         /MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**The converter:**

```
/// <summary>
/// multibinding, first binding is double? and second is string, both representing the same value
/// the double? value is for the viewmodel to use as normally intended
/// the string value is for the user not to have ui bugs
/// </summary>
class DoubleUserStringConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private OriginalConverterYouWanted converter;
    public DoubleUserStringConverter()
    {
        converter = new OriginalConverterYouWanted(); //single binding, not multi
        //for types "double" in the view model and "string" in the UI
        //in case of invalid strings, the double value sent to UI is null
    }

    //from view model to UI:
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[1] == null)  //null string means UI initialization, use double
            return converter.Convert(values[0], targetType, parameter, culture);
        else 
            return values[1]; //in the rest of the time, send user string to UI
    }

    //from UI to view model
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, 
                                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[] { 
            converter.ConvertBack(value, targetTypes[0], parameter, culture), //can be null
            value //string is always sent as is, no changes to what the user types
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of work compared to setting one property.

Comment: It is, but it's a complete solution, all the others have annoying UI bugs. Considering you normally already have a converter and a get/set/notify logic, it's not really that much.

Answer (score 1):

The decimal place disappearing is a "feature" they introduced whilst trying to fix something else. I thought it was .Net 4.0 this was introduced and people started noticing it was a breaking change but the documentation seems to imply .Net 4.5.

It usually occurs because you set updatesourcetrigger=propertychanged.

The simple fix is often to just remove that.

Because

```
, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus
```

Is the default behaviour for textbox text binding.

Alternatively, you could experiment with KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkcompatibilitypreferences.keeptextboxdisplaysynchronizedwithtextproperty(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

You can set that in Mainwindow before anything is displayed.

Comment: I tried your solutions, the `LostFocus` one is the best, but unfortunately it will still delete the entire text if the user leaves with invalid strings. If the grid has only one row, clicking outside the row doesn't change focus, there are specific places that must be clicked. -- For the compatibility solution, it was also deleting the entire text whenever validation failed.